# Making the output in forest a bracketed labels instead of tree

Tags: linguistics, forest

I have made a simple tree in the `forest` package, using the string of code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{exe}
\ex 

\begin{forest}

[DP
[D'
    [D]
    [NP
        [N'
            [N]]]]]

\end{forest}

\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

This gives my the output as a standard syntax tree. However, what I would like to do is something like the what the code below typesets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{exe}
\ex $[${\subscript{\scriptsize DP}}$[${\subscript{\scriptsize D'}} $[$ D $]$ $[${\subscript{\scriptsize NP}}  $[${\subscript{\scriptsize N'}} $[$N $]$ $]$ $]$ $]$ $]$

\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

But I wonder if there is an easy way of just making forest print the syntax tree as labeled brackets instead. There ought to be a simple command for this, but I just can't find it in the manual.

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Hi, it's best to post complete compilable documents rather than code fragments. In this case, for example, you've added fragments of `gb4e` code which are not relevant to the question, and not so obvious to non-linguists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code defines style `draw brackets`, which outputs the bracket representation, and shows two ways to use it. The first usage case replaces the default content of `draw tree stage` by the new style; the second one adds to it (and also prefixes each output by an `\ex` to start a new example).

(`amsmath` is loaded for `\text`, but one could also use `\mbox{\scriptsize ...}` and do without `amsmath`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\forestset{
  draw brackets/.style={
    TeX={[},
    if n children=0{
      TeX={ \forestoption{content} }
    }{
      TeX={$_{\text{\forestoption{content}}}$ }
    },
    for children=draw brackets,
    TeX={]\space},
  }
}  

\begin{document}

Bracket output instead of a tree:
\begin{exe}
\ex 
\begin{forest}
  draw tree stage/.style={for root'=draw brackets},
[DP
[D'
    [D]
    [NP
        [N'
            [N]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{exe}

Bracket output additional to the tree:
\begin{exe}
\begin{forest}
  draw tree stage/.style={TeX={\ex},for root'=draw tree,TeX={\ex},for root'=draw brackets},
[DP,baseline
[D'
    [D]
    [NP
        [N'
            [N]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```